# Can I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.5 to Kubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, kubuntu

I am planning to upgrade my PC from Ubuntu 12.04.5 to Kubuntu 14.04.5 when I return from vacation. Is that possible? Or should I do a clean installation?

Reasons for upgrading to Kubuntu and not to Ubuntu (you might agree with me):

1. Plasma 4 (way better design and look than Unity & GNOME Flashback):

   [image: Plasma 4 - Kubuntu 14.04 Live Session]
2. Great boot animation (instead of the boring Ubuntu dots which has oddly been kept up to 17.04):

   [image: Kubuntu 14.04 boot animation]
3. I think that it's a bit faster than Ubuntu 14.04 (even with GNOME Flashback)

I also have some questions about Kubuntu (since I will be a newbie):

1. In order to ask questions, can I post a thread on Ask Ubuntu or do I have to ask them on Kubuntu Forums?
2. Can I install .deb packages? Also, can I install packages from the terminal using `apt-get` or do I need to install special packages such as
   `kde-debtools` (I do not remember the name of the package, but I'm sure it was that. If I'm wrong,  let me know in the comments.)

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 and then install Kubuntu Plasma Desktop (*kubuntu-desktop*) in order to end up with a clumsy Kubuntu Plasma Desktop environment running on an Ubuntu 14.04 base. The nice way to do it is to do a fresh of install Kubuntu 16.04 which is Long Term Support release or Kubuntu 17.04 which is a regular release. In all of these cases you can use `apt` from the terminal to install .deb packages and get support from Ask Ubuntu the same as in Ubuntu.

Comment: OK,  thanks for answering. But, as I said above, Ubuntu 14.04.5 is slow on my PC (even with GNOME Flashback - Metacity). On my current Ubuntu 12.04.5 installation, I have installed the kubuntu-desktop package. It is great, however, as you said above, it's a little clumsy. For instance, I had to install my native language by myself by using kde-language-el-base. In conclusion, I want to install Kubuntu and not Ubuntu for the reasons above.  I find it better than Ubuntu (specifically in appearance).

Comment: So much for clumsy, on with nice. The familiar gdebi tool to install .deb files in Ubuntu is replaced by gdebi-kde in Kubuntu.

Comment: Can't I use the QApt Package Manager to install .deb packages?

Comment: You can install both of the packages alongside each other, they don't interfere with each other or either of them.